# Bootstrap columns skip two places

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have a PHP page with a few items on a page. I want three columns on large monitors but this is what it does. One column just skips two columns on the first page. It does not do that when there's four columns, but I want three.

There are no other style on columns so why does it do this?

[image: This is what "insperct element" reveals.]

Answer (score 5):

**Tanbi's** suggestion is good as per bootstrap guidelines but if you don't want to add `.row` `div` between the item `div` you can use below mentioned `css`

```
.col-md-4:nth-child(3n+3) + .col-md-4{clear:both;}
```

I'm not sure but I think it's work.

Answer (score 4):

its about elements height. you can use the *row* classed *divs* as follow.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...</div>
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">...</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not good because when there are supposed to be two columns there's always a row with two columns and a row with one column.

Comment: so you can try giving same height values for all _.item_ classed divs. the screenshot you attached seems like the second item is longer than others.   ** maybe using with _max-height_

Comment: For me, multiple rows weren't an easy option due to an existing structure, but setting a fixed height worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed this issue in Bootstrap 3

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```